# Create a new vector from single vector by manipulating Factors

Tags: r

Data Format

```
Date         Factor  Value
2014-01-01     x       10
2014-01-01     y       2
2014-01-02     x       20
2014-01-02     y       5
```

I would like to return a vector that is the result of the value for factor `x` divided by the value for factor `y` for each day.

The result looking like:

```
Date          Value
2014-01-01     5
2014-01-02     4
```

I am currently doing this with a nested `for` loop that looks up the values by matching the dates. Just wondering if there is an easier way that I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

If your data is ordered by Date and Factor, this will do. Select every second element of 'Value' using a logical vector, and calculate the ratio

```
ratio <- df$Value[c(TRUE, FALSE)] / df$Value[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
```

Put ratio in a data frame together with the dates

```
data.frame(Date = unique(df$Date), ratio)
#         Date ratio
# 1 2014-01-01     5
# 2 2014-01-02     4
```

If necessary, start by ordering the data by Date and Factor:

```
df <- df[order(df$Date, df$Factor), ]
```

Comment: Sorry I used a bad example of my sample data. The dates are all scattered about and not that neat. But thank you I learned something new from your post!

Comment: No problem. I added a way to order the data if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

There are certainly other ways to do it but I like `reshape2::dcast`.

Create example:

```
dd <- read.table(text="
Date         Factor  Value
2014-01-01     x       10
2014-01-01     y       2
2014-01-02     x       20
2014-01-02     y       5",header=TRUE)
```

Do it:

```
library(reshape2)
dd2 <- dcast(dd,Date~Factor)
with(dd2,data.frame(Date,Value=x/y))
```

Comment: Thank you. It's not grabbing the right values for some reason but I am using a data frame instead of a table so that maybe that is the problem. I am going to table my data and see if that corrects it. THANK YOU again!

Comment: not entirely clear what you mean -- this example *does* use a data frame.

Answer (score 2):

Or using some heavy artillery (`data.table`). If `dd` is your data set, consider:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dd)[, Value[1]/Value[2], by = Date]

##          Date V1
## 1: 2014-01-01  5
## 2: 2014-01-02  4
```

If your data is not ordered, you can sort first and then run:

```
setkey(setDT(dd), Date, Factor)[, Value[1]/Value[2], by = Date]

##          Date V1
## 1: 2014-01-01  5
## 2: 2014-01-02  4
```

Or just

```
setDT(dd)[, Value[Factor == "x"]/Value[Factor == "y"], by = Date]

##          Date V1
## 1: 2014-01-01  5
## 2: 2014-01-02  4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `unstack`, making use of the `formula` argument.

Using @BenBolker's data `dd`,

```
data.frame(Date = unique(dd$Date), Value = with(unstack(dd, Value~Factor), x/y))
#         Date Value
# 1 2014-01-01     5
# 2 2014-01-02     4
```